# Should I do anything with lacing on my cider ferment?

Tags: cider, primary-fermentation, foam

My first cider is in the primary fermenter, it's been 2 days.  There was a nice healthy looking head of foam on top for the first two days, but when I checked it today it was gone, and there was some lacing left on the side of the jug.  I was concerned it had stopped fermenting. But upon closer inspection, it's bubbling like crazy, they're just wicked small.

It's not attractive, but it doesnt look gross either.
[image]

There's no sign of blow off, the level is still the same and the sanitizer looks clear still.

Should I:

- Swirl it around a bit to try to reincorporate it into the liquid.
- Do nothing and get over it.
- Something else.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do nothing. That lacing is the residue of the foamy, yeasty head (krausen) clinging to the sides of the jug. There's no need to reincorporate it. Just let the cider finish fermenting.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a similar experience with fermenting apple cider: I had foam the first day, then no foam, though the cider is milky.  I'm thinking the yeast is still going, just slower than before.  Hope so.  Will watch for lacing.  It's 65 degrees and I used wine yeast.  I read that 65 is a good temperature for fermenting with wine yeast.